# Optimal Data Size To Overlap Kernel Execution and Data Transfer in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I have this cuda kernel that squares the elements of a square matrix and it works perfectly fun. I wanted to use 3 cuda streams and partition the input matrix into multiple chunks so that I perform H2D MemcpyAsync, kernel launch and D2H MemcpyAsync on a given chunk using the streams in a round-robin fashion. Here is the complete source code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
using namespace std;
__global__ void MatrixSquareKernel(int *inMatrix, int *outMatrix, size_t width, size_t     rowCount) {
    int myId = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    size_t crntRow = 0;
    if(myId < width) {
            size_t mId;
            while(crntRow < rowCount) {
                    mId = myId * width + crntRow;enter code here
                    outMatrix[mId] = inMatrix[mId] * inMatrix[mId];
                    crntRow++;
            }
    }
 }
 int main() {

    size_t count = width * width;
    size_t size = count * sizeof(int);

    vector<cudaStream_t> streams(strCount);

    for(int i = 0; i < strCount; i++)
            cudaStreamCreate(&streams[i]);

    int *h_inMatrix, *h_outMatrix;
    int *d_inMatrix, *d_outMatrix;

    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&h_inMatrix, size, cudaHostAllocDefault);
    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&h_outMatrix, size, cudaHostAllocDefault);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_inMatrix, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_outMatrix, size);

    for(int i = 0; i = count; i++)
            h_inMatrix[i] = i;

    size_t optimalRows = 16;
    size_t iter = width/optimalRows + ((width % optimalRows == 0)? 0: 1);

    size_t chnkOffset, chnkSize, strId, sentRows;

    struct timeval start, stop;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for(int i = 0; i < iter; i++){
            sentRows = i * optimalRows;
            chnkOffset = width * sentRows;
            chnkSize = width * optimalRows * sizeof(int);
            if(sentRows > width){
                    optimalRows -= sentRows - width; //Cutoff the extra rows in this chunk if it's larger than the remaining unsent rows
                    chnkSize = width * optimalRows * sizeof(int);
            }
            strId = i % strCount;
            cudaMemcpyAsync(d_inMatrix + chnkOffset, h_inMatrix + chnkOffset, chnkSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, streams.at(strId));
            MatrixSquareKernel<<<1, width, 0, streams.at(strId)>>>(d_inMatrix + chnkOffset, d_outMatrix + chnkOffset, width, optimalRows);
            cudaMemcpyAsync(h_outMatrix + chnkOffset, d_outMatrix + chnkOffset, chnkSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, streams.at(strId));
    }
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);

    double elapsedTime = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (start.tv_usec - stop.tv_usec)/1e6;

    cout<<"Elapsed Time: "<<elapsedTime<<endl;


    for(int i = 0; i < strCount; i++)
            cudaStreamDestroy(streams[i]);

    cudaFreeHost(h_inMatrix);
    cudaFreeHost(h_outMatrix);
    cudaFree(d_inMatrix);
    cudaFree(d_outMatrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Each of the chunks contains a certain number of rows, thus the variable `optimalRows`. For now, I'm assigning it a static value. But my objective is to calculate its value using the kernel's completion time on a row of the matrix and the transfer time of a row of the matrix. Let's say this value is `n`. To calculate it, I'm solving the equation `T_tr(n * width * sizeof(int)) = n * T_k + T_k-overhead` for `n`, where `T_tr(M)` is the transfer time of `M` bytes of data, which I can calculate by considering the bandwidth of the PCI/e bus, `T_k` is the completion time of squaring a single row of the matrix, and `T_k-overhead` is the cost of kernel launch. To measure the value of `T_k` and `T_k-overhead`, I launched the kernel twice, one is to square only a row of the matrix which takes `T_k1` time unit, and the other is to square two rows of the matrix which takes `T_k2` time unit. Taking the difference would be the kernel's completion time per a row of the matrix; thus,
`T_k = T_k2 - T_k1` and `T_k-overhead = 2*T_k1 - T_k2`. I thought solving the above equation for `n` given these parameters would give me a value for `n` greater than `1` but instead it is giving me a value less than `1`.

What is it that I am missing? I really appreciate your ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I thought solving the above equation for n given these parameters
>   would give me a value for n greater than 1 but instead it is giving me
>   a value less than 1.

You're are not minimizing `T_tr`, you're just looking for an `n` that satisfies a condition involving `T_tr`.

A value less than 1 makes sens. A value of zero is an obvious solution and gives you

```
T_tr(0) = T_k-overhead // always true
```

Also `T_k-overhead = 2*T_k1 - T_k2` is correct iff

```
N * size(T_k) == N * T_tr(T_k) // considering the problem perfectly linear
```

Since your problem is linear the condition is true when you're GPU utilization is maximal.

This actually what you should first do:

1. Maximize GPU utilization
2. Overlap transfer and execution

To maximize utilization you need to increase `n` until execution increases linearly. You also need to optimize you kernel by improving your memory pattern:

Instead of processing `rowCount` per kernel-thread and having a stride in memory access you should square a single matrix element per thread with contiguous memory accesses per warp.
This would also simplify the kernel and this also often increases  gpu usage (for instance using less registers per warp)

For overlapping execution and transfer you already know how to use asynchronous calls + streams

Comment: I can't minimize `T_tr`, it is simply a function of the data size, `T_tr(M) = Mbytes/BW`. In principle, `T_tr(0)` is undefined not equal to `T_k-overhead`. Moreover, I can't quite understand how you come up with this `N * size(T_k) == N * T_tr(T_k)`, `T_k(T_k)` doesn't make any sense. When it comes to processing, `rowCount` is not processed per kernel-thread, instead each element in a row is processed by a unique thread; thus, for `rowCount x N` matrix the kernel will be launched with N threads, where thread `i` processes the `rowCount` elements in column `i`.

Comment: Sorry I'm using a slightly different terminology from yours. In my answer `T_tr(x)` is the time required to process the problem `x` and minimizing `T_tr(x)` is the *main* goal. My answer is based on a behavior you can observe on most GPUs: if you have a GPU with 1000 ALU the time to process 1000 elements should be roughly the same as processing a single element. Also because of pipelining, out of order exec, caching... processing 100K elements can be only slightly slower than processing a single element (not 100K slower). So Make sure the GPU is fully exploited when you split execution